# Database into an array indexed

Tags: php, mysql

How to transform data from a database into an array indexed?
from:

```
$bb = mysql_query("SELECT kalori FROM bb_temp ORDER BY density DESC");
//field kalori contains=(16,12,23,13,9,10,18)
```

become :

```
Array
(
  [0] => 16
  [1] => 12
  [2] => 23
  [3] => 13
  [4] => 9
  [5] => 10
  [6] => 18
)
```

Thank you...

Comment: your `kalori` field shouldn't ever contain comma separated values, by the way. Read about "Database normalization"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your field realy contains a comma separated string then you can use

```
$result = mysql_result($bb,0);
$array = explode("," $result);
print_r($array);
```

If each row contains one value then you can use

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($bb){
   $array[] = $row[0];
}

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$kalori = "16,12,23,13,9,10,18";
$data = explode(',', $kalori);

print_R($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this...

```
$bb = mysql_query("SELECT kalori FROM bb_temp ORDER BY density DESC");

$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($bb))
{
array_push($arr,$row['kalori']);
}

print_r($arr);
```

<sup>Disclaimer : Stop using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. Switch to MySQLi or PDO.</sup>

Comment: What if the output: 16,12,23,13,9,10,18?  and fixed arrays?

Answer (score 0):

What if the output:

```
16,12,23,13,9,10,18
```

and fixed arrays?